# C# - MongoDB - Query for value in array

Tags: c#, mongodb, querying

I've been looking around stack for quite a while now, and I'm seeing **a lot of questions resembling this one**, but none so far has been asking exactly this.

I'm new to MongoDB *(in fact I'm new to databases in general)* and I'm trying to query for a set of documents where one of the fields is an array and contains at-least one integer from a set of reference integers.

This a rough version of the data structure I'm using.

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("577686c89aff4e2e986923c1"),
  "RowSpan" : [
      {
          "PathID" : 1,,
          "Rows" : [108, 206, 399],
      }],
  "Name" : "BICT_1_2_1" 
}
```

I want to find all documents containing a Rows array with at-least one number matching my reference numbers. 
*(The **reference numbers** are highly **arbitrary**, for now lets say they are **108** and **399**)*

I've been looking at [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) but I'm not sure how to combine these for the result I'm looking for.

Right now I'm trying to find, what feels like a workaround, using `Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In`  in conjunction with `Builders<BsonArray>.Filter.ElemMatch` but I'm not having much luck.

Any help i much appreciated!

---

**Update**

After some more searching and trial and error I've decided to go with an `AnyIn` filter.

```
filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.AnyIn("RowSpan.Rows", new int[]{ 108, 399 });
```

This solution is probably not the most optimal, so I'm still open for suggestions.

Comment: If you're new to database and you want to try out a document db, and you don't have to stick with MongoDB, then I would highly recommend RavenDB. It is built for c# and therefor follows the c# patterns and styles. So you may find it easier to do what you want.

Comment: @CallumLinington Thanks for the tip! 
If it weren't for the fact that I've already got MongoBD highly integrated in the project (and I'm on somewhat of a tight schedule) I would have defiantly given it more of a closer look. How ever the case, I'm stuck with Mongo for the time being.

Comment: Use "Rows"':{$in:[108,399]} in your query.

Comment: @IndrajeetSingh wouldn't that only return documents with BOTH 108 and 399?
I want documents with either or both.

Comment: It will be return both.